# Specific regular expression not valid in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to Replace with C# the content inside id in this html:

```
    <tr class=\"ListRow EvenListRow\" id=\"e2505_735.8429.2125\">
```

so I use this regular expression that works in php.

```
id=\\"(.*?)\\"
```

Then I try to use this regular expression to do a Replace in C# in this way:

```
//htmlSourceReportInfo contains html information with the previous said html code.
htmlSourceReportInfo = htmlSourceReportInfo.Replace(@"(id=\\""(.*?)\\"")", "");
```

It does not do anything.

Comment: You are not using a regex based replacement with `String.Replace()`. Use `Regex.Replace`.

Comment: are you trying to delete the `id...` part?

Comment: @MongZhu I just trying to delete the code inside: e2505_735.8429.2125

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have tried Regex.Replace(htmlSourceReportInfo, @"(id=\\""(.*?)\\"")", "");, but it is the same result.

Comment: Yes, because you use backslashes, and you should not have used them. More, you do not need parentheses. And in any case, to work with HTML, you'd better use HtmlAgilityPack or any other HTML parsing library.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
var text = "<tr class=\"ListRow EvenListRow\" id=\"e2505_735.8429.2125\">";
string result = Regex.Replace(text, "id=\"[^\"]*\"", "id=\"\"");
```

Please note that the Regex.Replace does not change the string itself, it rather returns the changed string.